# Connection Timeout in URLConnection

Tags: java

I am using the below code to get the data from webservice. But the behavior is unexpected. It gives the data 7-8 times when i hit through code, but after that connection timeout error. Any Solution??

```
  URL url = new URL(webPage);  
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();  
System.out.println("Connection Timeout  =====  "+urlConnection.getConnectTimeout());  
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);  
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);  
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();  
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Exception is : `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

Comment: Maybe the url has a limit or something? Some services don't allow to be called more than a few times within a given time.

Answer (score 0):

This is may be internet connection issue (i.e disconnected or slow). Increase your timeout duration.

Comment: It could definitely be a internet issue but I dont see any point increasing timeout seeing as its already 20 seconds